# Inserting file names as column values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several txt files. Each file has the columns of data separated by a comma. And each has its own individual file name.

So far I have combined these files into one big data frame, using the following code:

```
files = list.files()
data2=lapply(files, read.table, header=FALSE, sep=",")
data_rbind <- do.call("rbind", data2) 
colnames(data_rbind)[c(1,2,3)]<-c("name", "sex", "amount")
```

This returns:

> name sex amount
>
> Anna   F   24567
>
> Emma   F   23210
>
> Isabelle F  31212
>
> Amanda  F   22631

I would like to add a 4th column which specifies next to each line of data, the name of the file that the data was originally sourced from.

So, for example, if the first file 'example1.txt' contained the following:

> Anna, F, 24567
>
> Emma, F, 23210
>
> Isabelle, F, 31212

And the second file 'example2.txt' contained the following:

> Amanda, F, 22631
>
> Sara, F, 41355
>
> Katie, F, 2387

I would like to get the following:

> Name Sex Amount Year
>
> Anna F 24567 example1.txt
>
> Emma F 23210 example1.txt
>
> Amanda F 22631 example2.txt
>
> Sara F 41355 example2.txt
>
> Katie F 2387 example2.txt

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
files = list.files()
data2=lapply(files, read.table, header=FALSE, sep=",")
for (i in 1:length(data2)){data2[[i]]<-cbind(data2[[i]],files[i])}
data_rbind <- do.call("rbind", data2) 
colnames(data_rbind)[c(1,2,3,4)]<-c("name", "sex", "amount","year")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
   nm1 <- c("Name", "Sex", "Amount", "Year")
  files <- list.files(pattern="^example")
  files
  #[1] "example1.txt" "example2.txt"

  setNames(do.call(rbind,Map(`cbind`, 
           lapply(files, read.table, sep=","), V4=files)), nm1)

   #       Name Sex Amount         Year
   #1     Anna   F  24567 example1.txt
   #2     Emma   F  23210 example1.txt
   #3 Isabelle   F  31212 example1.txt
   #4   Amanda   F  22631 example2.txt
   #5     Sara   F  41355 example2.txt
   #6    Katie   F   2387 example2.txt
```

Or use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setnames(rbindlist(Map(`cbind`,lapply(files, fread),files)),nm1)[]
 #     Name Sex Amount         Year
 #1:     Anna   F  24567 example1.txt
 #2:     Emma   F  23210 example1.txt
 #3: Isabelle   F  31212 example1.txt
 #4:   Amanda   F  22631 example2.txt
 #5:     Sara   F  41355 example2.txt
 #6:    Katie   F   2387 example2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
data2 = lapply(files, function(x) {
    res <- read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep=",")
    res$year <- x
    res
}, header=FALSE, sep=",")

data_rbind <- do.call("rbind", data2) 
colnames(data_rbind) <- c("name", "sex", "amount", "year")
```

Comment: It works great up until the last line of code where it gives the error:
"Error in C(1, 2, 3) <- c("name", "sex", "amount", "year") : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object"
?

Comment: Yea, I just copied this part and didn't check it, it should work now.